# Flutter iOS build is stuck on "Running Xcode Build"

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I recently got a mac to be able to test the iOS applications I made with Flutter/Dart. But when trying to transfer all my files to a Mac and try to test it, it gets on "Running Xcode Build."

I am importing 2 things in my pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependicies:
  flutter:
    sdk:
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
      firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+10
```

In my podfile, which I was told to download on the google admobs documentation I have

```
pod 'Google-Mobile_Ads_SDK"
```

My Flutter Doctors reads:

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/priscilla/Desktop/Temp/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (5 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/priscilla/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    ✗ Could not determine java version

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • 754DF0BD-203E-4A0A-B785-E92D4B1D9C38 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

And the change to my info.plist is: (The actual app ID is in my code, just didn't want to post it here)

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>[APP_ID]</string>
```

If I were to create a new Flutter project from scratch, the given code runs perfectly fine. It is just when I try to import the files the project on my windows PC to my Mac.

I think a solution would be to create a new Flutter project and while creating import my files, but I am not sure how to do that. So at the moment, I created a new Flutter project, deleted all the files that comes loaded initially, then replaced them with my project files.

Comment: try to run `flutter clean`, I don't know if it will fix, but for sure it can help

Comment: @Tizianoreica I tried that, still got stuck on running xcode build

Comment: did you tried running flutter clean and pod install? and rebuild?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had removed the external devices specifically external monitors attached to Mac.
Then made the build.

My build time came from 10min on average to 0.5 to 2 min max.

Comment: That's ridiculous. Unplugging external display from my Macbook reduces compilation time from ~750 seconds to about 25. Like, why It is even relevant?

Comment: I think it might be due to some gpu allocation or cpu allocation issue. I don’t know. I am not an expert though :)

Comment: Do you know, if the problem was present before BigSur update?

Comment: Big Sur was released on Nov 12. I posted on nov 9th. To get solution it took me time. Hence no matter how I see it, problem is present even before big sur.  ;)

Comment: As soon as I unplugged the external monitor, build completed.

Comment: Even without changing anything, restarting the PC, building the project takes long time. Once it builds, hot reload etc working fine but every morning rebuilding takes ~10 mins. Hope Flutter devs can change this.

Comment: I think its about Memory Leak of windowserver. I really can't understand how apple didn't solve this problem yet.

Comment: I have done everything but nothing working for me, i have to restart everything and run build on xcode first.

Answer (score 35):

in my case, I use Firebase Firestore.

it doesn't stuck actually, but it takes waaaay too long to build in Xcode. don't forget to improve iOS build times as per the official documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment) (don't forget to pick Dart Flutter as the language), and then scroll to find the optional section about how to Improve iOS & macOS build times by including the pre-compiled framework.

> Currently, the Firestore SDK for iOS depends on code that can take
> upwards of 5 minutes to build in Xcode. To reduce build times
> significantly, you can use a pre-compiled version by adding this line
> to the target 'Runner' do block in your Podfile:

**please open that documentation to improve the build time, because the code maybe updated.**

the code will be like this

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => 'x.xx.x'
  # ...
end
```

after adding that 1 line on your iOS podfile, don't forget to do `flutter clean` before rebuild the project. the second time you build the project it should be faster

NOTE:

if there is an error, then please ensure the tag in pod `:tag => 'X.X.X`' from the code in documentation is suitable with your cloud_firestore package version. sometimes the official documentation is not updated like the issue in [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6752)

Comment: this was the case for me. I though it was stuck but it was the firestore taking huge amount of time

Answer (score 1):

iOS(Build) IPA building was taking around **14456.14 Sec** i.e (more than **4 hrs**) after updating to the below version it was reduced to **2143.3 Sec** i.e. (less than **40 mins**)

1. Changed From:

   ```
   environment:
   sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
   ```

   Changes To:

   ```
   environment:
   sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
   ```
2. Change the whole project to Null-safety

   Please follow https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Answer (score 1):

If your build is stuck on Running Xcode build..., try the solution below:

cd Project Folder >

rm -R build

rm .dart_tool

rm .packages

rm -Rf ios/Pods

rm -Rf ios/.symlinks

rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework

rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec

pod cache clean --all

cd ios > pod deintegrate

pod setup

arch -x86_64 pod install
cd ..

flutter clean -v

flutter pub get

flutter clean && flutter run

If the above fails, clone the project again and flutter run.

Answer (score 0):

In My Experience, this first build indeed takes a long time - but after you run it once - the build time is reasonable.

Comment: Also on Simulator?